# how to run multiple unit tests using same data

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I'm trying to implement unit tests for a rest api I created. When I run the tests separately, they pass. But when I try to run all of them in 1 go, only 1 passes.

I know it has something to do with way I try to use the same data in evry test. I found a solution by using a new database(name) for every test. But I was wondering if this is the correct way to go about it? Since I think there has to be a cleaner way. I looked into the IDisposable method, but I coudn't get it to work.

This is how I put data in the db to test against:

```
public class GameTestShould
{
    private static GameService gameService;

    private readonly DbContextOptions<GameContext> options;
    public readonly Game testGame;
    public readonly User testUser;
    public Location testLocation;


    public GameTestShould()
    {
        //Arrange For the all tests
        options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "GameTestDB").Options;
        //arrange
        using (var globalContext = new GameContext(options))
        {
            gameService = new GameService(globalContext);

            var testUser = new User()
            {
                Username = "tempUser",
                Password = "123456"
            };
            globalContext.Users.Add(testUser);
            var location2 = new Location()
            {
                LocName = "Standbeeld Stadhuis",
                LocLat = 51.220884,
                LocLong = 4.398995,
                LocDescription = "Standbeeld Vrijheid blijheid nabij stadhuis."
            };
            var location3 = new Location()
            {
                LocName = "Het Steen",
                LocLat = 51.222773,
                LocLong = 4.397367,
                LocDescription = "Het Steen"
            };
            var location4 = new Location()
            {
                LocName = "Pieter Paul Rubens",
                LocLat = 51.219326,
                LocLong = 4.401576,
                LocDescription = "Groenplaats, standbeeld Pieter Paul Rubens."
            };
            var location5 = new Location()
            {
                LocName = "Politiekantoor",
                LocLat = 51.230754,
                LocLong = 4.4174065,
                LocDescription = "Politiekantoor"
            };
            globalContext.Add(location2);
            globalContext.Add(location3);
            globalContext.Add(location4);
            globalContext.Add(location5);

            var suspect0 = new Suspect()
            {
                //  SuspectId = 1,
                SusName = "Miss Scarlett",
                SusWeapon = "Rope",
                SusDescription = "Ms. Vivienne Sakura Scarlet",
                SusImgUrl = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/95/ce/3d/95ce3da06af8b1c09a4b2d4fa603b7a0.jpg",
            };
            var suspect1 = new Suspect()
            {
                SusName = "Mr. Green",
                SusWeapon = "Wooden cross",
                SusDescription = "Rev. Jonathan Green.",
                SusImgUrl = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/447953368271814657/Inf33QvJ.jpeg",
            };
            var suspect2 = new Suspect()
            {
                SusName = "Colonel Mustard",
                SusWeapon = "Gun",
                SusDescription = "Col. Michael Mustard",
                SusImgUrl = "https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/07/04/08/unspecified-3.jpg?width=1368&height=912&fit=bounds&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=70",
            };

            var suspect3 = new Suspect()
            {
                SusName = "Dr.Orchid",
                SusWeapon = "Syringe",
                SusDescription = "A Doctor, Elegant ",
                SusImgUrl = "https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/07/04/08/unspecified-4.jpg?width=1368&height=912&fit=bounds&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=70",
            };
            globalContext.Suspects.Add(suspect0);
            globalContext.Suspects.Add(suspect1);
            globalContext.Suspects.Add(suspect2);
            globalContext.Suspects.Add(suspect3);

            var clue0 = new Clue()
            {
                ClueName = "RansomPuzzle"
            };
            var clue1 = new Clue()
            {
                ClueName = "ARKnife"
            };
            var clue2 = new Clue()
            {
                ClueName = "ARRope"
            };
            globalContext.Clues.Add(clue0);
            globalContext.Clues.Add(clue1);
            globalContext.Clues.Add(clue2);
            globalContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is first test

```
   [Fact]
    public void Throw_AppExceptionTooManyItems_Over8ItemsAdded()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options; 

        using (var globalContext = new GameContext(options))
        {
            gameService = new GameService(globalContext);
            //act and assert 
            Exception ex = Assert.Throws<AppException>(() => gameService.CreateGame(1, 2));
            Assert.Contains("between", ex.Message);               
        }          
     }
```

2nd test. Here (I think) I make another db, but doesn't this just leave the data from previous test laying around? So if I were to make alot of tests, woudn't it slow down the test process?

```
   [Fact]
    public void Throw_AppExceptionWrongUser()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;

        using (var globalContext = new GameContext(options))
        {
            gameService = new GameService(globalContext);
            //act and assert 
            Exception ex = Assert.Throws<AppException>(() => gameService.CreateGame(2, 3));
            Assert.Equal("User does not exist.", ex.Message);
        }            
    }
}
```

}

Are there better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each test a new database otherwise, as you have seen, the db is reused for each test and can affect the results.

You can read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests) which uses a new `InMemoryDatabase` for each test. I give the database the same name as the test method (just for clarity).

You could move your db code to a private method and re-use that in each test e.g.

```
[Fact]
public void Throw_AppExceptionWrongUser()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;

        using (var globalContext = CreateNewContext(options))
        {
            gameService = new GameService(globalContext);
            //act and assert 
            Exception ex = Assert.Throws<AppException>(() => gameService.CreateGame(2, 3));
            Assert.Equal("User does not exist.", ex.Message);
        }            
    }
}

private GameContext CreateNewContext(DbContextOptions options)
{
    var globalContext = new GameContext(options);

    var testUser = new User()
        {
            Username = "tempUser",
            Password = "123456"
        };
    globalContext.Users.Add(testUser);

    return globalContext;
}
```

Performance shouldn't be affected that much, unless you are populating the in memory database with lots of data (but based on your example code that doesn't seem a problem). One way to find out is to write the tests and measure it :-)

If performance is an issue then you should consider only populating the database with the data you need for the specific test. I would recommend looking at the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for populating the database if you want to go down that route.